# Sort in Python changing column order

Tags: python, sorting

I am reading data from csv n storing in dict... colName:Value ... format...
but order of cols get messed..
I want in same order as csv

Code:

```
def sort_csv():

    data = list(csv.DictReader(open("Bl.csv")))
    op = open("Bl_S.csv", "wb")
    wr = csv.writer(op, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    sorted_data = sorted(data, key = lambda d:(d['ID'], d['Begin']))
    headers = sorted_data[0].keys()
    wr.writerow(headers)
    for i in sorted_data:
         wr.writerow(i.values())

    op.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered, so when you do:

```
headers = sorted_data[0].keys()
```

the order of `headers` is basically random. Also the return value of `values()` is random too, hence even if you are lucky and the the correct order for the `headers` when you write the rows using:

```
wr.writerow(i.values())
```

The elements in different rows need not have the same order.

You must read the headers from the file separately. Also it's probably better to use a `DictWriter` in your case. For example:

```
with open('Block.csv') as infile, open('Block_sorted.csv', 'wb') as op:
    data = sorted(csv.DictReader(infile), key=lambda d: (d['Track_ID'], d['Kp_Begin']))

    # read the column names in the correct order.
    infile.seek(0)
    headers = infile.readline().split()

    wr = csv.DictWriter(op, headers, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerows(data)

    # don't need to close() files when using "with"
```

Comment: I'll note that if a `dict` isn't modified, it's guaranteed that `zip(d.keys(), d.values())` is equal to `d.items()`.

Comment: @JonClements That holds *on the same `dict`*, but each row is a distinct `dict` and thus there is no guarantee that the order of the *headers* `keys()` is the same as the *rows* `values()` and even that all rows have the same order.

Comment: Indeed. I just thought "... headers is basically random. Also the return value of values() is random too" makes it sound like dictionaries are completely unpredictable...